# Changing user properties in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script that creates a user and assigns the password and the user to a group but I need to get 2 check boxes ticked - 'User cannot change password' and 'Password never expires' but for the life of me I cannot find out how to do this.

My script so far is this:-

```
# Create User and add to IGNITEWEBUSERS Group
$user = $domain

# If more then 15 chars trim to just 15 chars
$user = $user.substring(0, 15)
$user = $user + "_web"

# Generate Random Complex Password
# Generate a password with 2 non-alphanumeric character.
$Length = 10
$Assembly = Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$RandomComplexPassword = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword($Length,2)
$password = $RandomComplexPassword

$group = 'IGNITEWEBUSERS'
$objOu = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer"
$objUser = $objOU.Create("User", $user)
$objUser.setpassword($password)
$objUser.SetInfo()
$objUser.description = $domain + " IIS User"
$objUser.SetInfo()
$OBjOU = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$group,group"
$OBjOU.Add("WinNT://$computer/$user")
```

That works and does what it should do but anyone know how I can set those 2 check boxes?
Various threads suggest something similar to `Set-ADUser -CannotChangePassword:$true` but am not using Active Directory and this doesn't work.

Your advice appreciated

Paul

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it figured out this morning:-

```
$objUser.UserFlags = 64 + 65536 # ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE + ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
```

Comment: Not exactly obvious is it!

Answer (score 4):

Set the **useraccountcontrol** property. You can find a list of useraccountcontrol flags here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144

Add the values of the flags you want (NORMAL_ACCOUNT = 512, PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE = 64, DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD = 65536) for a total of 66112, and set the property to that number:

```
$obUser.useraccountcontrol = 66112
```

BTW, you only need to call the **SetInfo()** method once at the end, after setting all the properties you want to set.

Comment: I get the following error:   E:\Domains\ignite.flinthosts.co.uk\wwwroot\domains\processes\Domain>PowerShell.exe -noexit E:\processes\Domain\createuser.ps1
Cannot set the Value property for PSMemberInfo object of type "System.Management.Automation.PSMethod".
At E:\processes\Domain\createuser.ps1:24 char:10
+ $objUser. <<<< useraccountcontrol = 66112
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Comment: Got it figured out this morning - $objUser.UserFlags = 64 + 65536 # ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE + ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD

Answer (score 0):

Use WMI to get the user account:

```
# Use this filter so WMI doesn't spend forever talking to domain controllers.
$user = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter ("Domain='{0}' and Name='{1}'" -f $env:ComputerName,$Username)
$user.PasswordChangeable = $false
$user.PasswordExpires = $false
$user.Put()
```

Comment: I get the following errors when adding that...

Property 'PasswordChangeable' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.

Property 'PasswordExpires' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
+ $user.Put <<<< ()

Comment: Pass `$user` to `Get-Member` and see what properties it has, e.g. `$user | Get-Member`.

Comment: I get 'no object has been specified to the get-member cmdlet'. As you can probably tell I'm very new to powershell so go easy :)

Comment: Then it looks like `Get-WmiObject` isn't returning a user.  Does the user exist?  Is it local? What are you setting the `$username` variable too?